# Shortest path on a sphere direction descision

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'm trying to write an algorithm that does the following.

Given a current position (in Azimuth and Inclination) and a target position (again in A, I) in what direction should I travel to travel over the shortest path. The return value could be something like a vector A = -1, I = +0.5, that I can then scale for step size/time.

The shortest path can be found by using [a great circle](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ShortestPathBetweenTwoPointsOnASphere/), this is easy to visualize, but it's hard to implement like above because my coordinate system isn't continuous.

My coordinate system is as followed (imagine standing in front of the sphere)

The azimuth is 0 ~ pi when traveling along the equator along the front side, it's 0 ~ -pi when traveling along the equator along the rear side.

The inclination is 0~+pi when traveling from the top to the bottom of the sphere.

So given this non-continuous coordinate system, how do I create a decision function that says 'increase A' to travel over the shortest path?

Comment: ying to understand your problem.  What prevents you to work in a (0 - 2 Pi) coordinate system, which seems known to you and then do _If (a>Pi) then a=Pi - a_ ?

Comment: You mean for the azimuth? It's easy to map -pi~pi to 0~2pi if that makes finding the shortest path easier, but how would the total algorithm look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of alternatives.  The first is to use a [Haversine formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).  There is some Javascript source code [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  It requires using more traditional lat / lon where the equator is at 0 latitude and the poles are at +/- π or +/- 90° latitude (depending on your units) and longitude is in the range [-180°, 180°) or [-π, π) again depending on your units.  You can repeatedly find the midpoint until you have an approximate path that suites your needs.  The azimuth / inclination vector would just be the difference in lat / lon between two adjacent points, though over time this will likely induce an error if you repeatedly apply those lat / lon deltas to the location of your agent.

Another approach that may work well for you is to transform your spherical coordinates of your starting and ending location to cartesian coordinates, call them points ***u***<sub>b</sub> and ***u***<sub>e</sub> for beginning and end points.  The normal vector ***v*** of the great circle connecting the two points is the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two (i.e. ***v*** = ***u***<sub>b</sub> x ***u***<sub>e</sub>) and the angle θ is just the arccosine of the normalized inner product (ie. θ = cos<sup>-1</sup>( (***u***<sub>e</sub> ∙ ***u***<sub>e</sub>) / (|***u***<sub>b</sub>||***u***<sub>e</sub>)).  You can then use [quaternion rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) and iterate from 0 to θ about the vector ***v*** to actually navigate the path.  With this approach, the actual instantaneous vector at some point ***p*** along the path is just the ***p*** x ***v***, or you can just approximate this by using the cartesian difference between two adjacent points along the path.

Comment: Hey andand, I really love your explanation of the cartesian coordinate solution, I first converted to spherical coordinates because I thought that this would be easier. I'm going to have a lot of objects on the sphere, so I'm going to try the Haversine formulation first to keep a uniform coordinate system, however if that fails I'm pretty sure I can implement the cartesian solution and be pretty happy about that (I've already got code to convert to and from cart).